# Catastrophic backtracking issue with regular expression on long names

Tags: regex

I am currently trying to validate a regex pattern for a names list among other things.
It actually works so far except when I try to test the limits. If the name is quite long, a maximum of 128 characters is allowed and then at the end a character which is defined in an inner group, such as:. a separator e.g. Space or a puncture, catastrophic backtracking occurs. Somehow I don't quite understand that because I would assume that group one `(?:[\p{L}\p{Nd}\p{Ps}])+` 1 x must be there, group `(?:\p{Zs}\p{P}|\p{P}\p{Zs}|[\p{P}\p{Zs}])?` is optional and if the group has to be valid at the end `(?:[\p{L}\p{Nd}\p{Pe}.])`. The rear 2 groups can occur more often.

***Full pattern***

`^(?!.{129})(?!.["])(?:[\p{L}\p{Nd}\p{Ps}])+(?:(?:\p{Zs}\p{P}|\p{P}\p{Zs}|[\p{P}\p{Zs}])?(?:[\p{L}\p{Nd}\p{Pe}.]))*$`

***Tests & Samples***

https://regex101.com/r/6E0Khd/1

Comment: It seems that changing the `+` after the first consuming pattern will already solve the problem: `^(?!.{129})(?!.["])[\p{L}\p{Nd}\p{Ps}]++(?:(?:\p{Zs}\p{P}|\p{P}\p{Zs}|[\p{P}\p{Zs}])?(?:[\p{L}\p{Nd}\p{Pe}.]))*$`, see https://regex101.com/r/3rdcm8/3

Comment: Unfortunately, I forgot to write the additional information that I want to use it in Javascript. Unfortunately, there is no debugger under Javascript on the Regex page, so it is not based on Javascript. Changed link in description, and thanks for your Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-phrase the pattern in such a way so that the consequent regex parts could not match at the same location inside the string.

You can use

```
^(?!.{129})(?!.")[\p{L}\p{Nd}\p{Ps}][\p{L}\p{Nd}\p{Pe}.]*(?:(?:\p{Zs}\p{P}?|\p{P}\p{Zs}?)[\p{L}\p{Nd}\p{Pe}.]+)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3rdcm8/2).

Your regex was `^<Lookahead_1><Lookahead_2><P_I>+(?:<OPT_SEP>?<P_II>)*$`. You need to make sure your string only starts with a char that matches `<P_I>` pattern, the rest of the chars can match `<P_II>` pattern. So, it should look like `^<Lookahead_1><Lookahead_2><P_I><P_II>*(?:<SEP><P_II>+)*$`. Note the `P_I` pattern is used to match the first char only, `P_II` pattern is added right after `P_I` to match zero or more chars matching that pattern, `SEP` pattern is now obligatory and `P_II` pattern is quantified with `+`.

I also shrunk the `(?:\p{Zs}\p{P}|\p{P}\p{Zs}|[\p{P}\p{Zs}])` pattern into `(?:\p{Zs}\p{P}?|\p{P}\p{Zs}?)` (it matches either a horizontal whitespace and an optional punctuation proper symbol, or an optional punctuation proper symbol followed with an optional horizontal whitespace.

Note that `\p{Zs}` does not match a TAB char, you may want to use `[\p{Zs}\t]` instead.

Comment: Many thanks. This solved the catastrophic backtracking issue. Maybe another idea how I can consistently ban QUOTATION MARK?

Comment: @Mario `"` and `'` are from `Po` category. So, you might want to replace `\p{P}` with `[^\P{P}'"]` everywhere.

Comment: How would u replace ```[\p{P}\p{Zs}]``` where ```\p{P}``` is inside brackets?

Comment: @Mario I have already replaced it. See my answer.

Comment: Your regex demo link nor your description would not show me the replacement of ```\p{P}``` with ```[^\P{P}'"]``` in any version.

Comment: @Mario That replacement operation is straight-forward, https://regex101.com/r/3rdcm8/4.